# Analytical form of 2d integrals relevant to graphene

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, special-functions

This question is continuation of my previous [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/204877/elliptic-integrals/204934?noredirect=1#comment528857_204934).
Alex Trounev was very helpful in fixing a crucial typo in the analytic solution known from the article "*Density Dependent Exchange Contribution to ∂/∂ and Compressibility in Graphene*". Here, the question is about obtaining the analytic solution in fully automatic way with MA. It consists of 2 parts:

1. I know the analytic solution for `xe` (but do not know how
   to obtain it) and I can verify it numerically.
2. I have numerical solution for `xi` and a fixed analytical solution that works in some parameter range.

   I am asking because I feel that there are other typos that I am not able to fix myself.

---

We will be needing some auxiliary functions [Eqs.(5,6) in the [paper]](http://www.physics.uakron.edu/dept/faculty/benhu/Reprints/PhysRevLett_99_226801_compressibility_graphene.pdf) that I define beforehands

```
(*i[1]=Integrate[EllipticK[y^2]-EllipticE[y^2],{y,0,1/x},Assumptions->x>1]*)
i[1]=1/(2 x) π (-HypergeometricPFQ[{-(1/2),1/2,1/2},{1,3/2},1/x^2]+HypergeometricPFQ[{1/2,1/2,1/2},{1,3/2},1/x^2]);

(*i[2]=Integrate[(EllipticK[y^2]-EllipticE[y^2]-π/4 y^2)/y^3,{y,0,x},Assumptions->0≤x≤1]*)
i[2]=3/256 π x^2 (HypergeometricPFQ[{1,1,3/2,5/2},{2,3,3},x^2]+3 HypergeometricPFQ[{1,1,5/2,5/2},{2,3,3},x^2]);

f[x_] =Piecewise[{{EllipticE[x^2],x<=1},{x EllipticE[1/x^2]-(x-1/x)EllipticK[1/x^2],True}}];
h[x_] =Piecewise[{{x(π/4Log[4/x]-π/8)-x i[2],x<=1},{x i[1],x>1}}];
h2[x_]=Piecewise[{{x(π/4Log[4/x]+π/8)-x i[2],x<=1},{x i[1],x>1}}];
```

*These expressions I want to reproduce with MA*

## Calculation of `xe`

With the definitions

```
p[k_,q_,θ_]:=Sqrt[k^2+q^2-2 k q Cos[θ]]
Fs[k_,q_,θ_,si_,sf_]:=1/2(1+si sf (k-q Cos[θ] )/p[k,q,θ] )
n[k_,s_]:=UnitStep[1- k s]
n0[s_]:=1/2(1-s)
δn[k_,s_]:=n[k,s]-n0[s]
```

we get **the first 2d integral** that I want to know how to compute analytically

```
xeN[k_?NumericQ,s_]:=-(1/(2π))NIntegrate[
Fs[k,q,θ,s,1]δn[p[k,q,θ],1]+Fs[k,q,θ,s,-1]δn[p[k,q,θ],-1],
{q,0,∞},{θ,0,2π},PrecisionGoal->2]

xeN[k_?NumericQ,0]:=-(1/(2π))NIntegrate[UnitStep[1- p[k,q,θ]],
{q,0,∞},{θ,0,2π},PrecisionGoal->4]  (* sum of the 1 and -1 cases*)
```

Here, `xe` is the known analytical expression for `xeN` **but how to get this with MA?**:

```
xe[k_,s_]:=1/π (-f[k]-s h[k])
```

### Verification

is time consuming

```
eval[ 1]=Table[{k,xeN[k, 1]},{k,0.1,2,0.2}]
eval[-1]=Table[{k,xeN[k,-1]},{k,0.1,2,0.2}]
eval[ 0]=Table[{k,xeN[k, 0]},{k,0.1,2,0.2}];   (*the sum of the 1 and -1 cases*)
```

and plot

```
Plot[{xe[k,1],xe[k,-1],xe[k,1]+xe[k,-1]},{k,0,2},
PlotRange->{-1.05,0},PlotTheme->{"FrameGrid","BoldColor"},FrameStyle->14,FrameLabel->{"k","Subscript[x, e]"},Epilog->{PointSize[Medium],Blue,Point[eval[1]],Orange,Point[eval[-1]],Red,Point[eval[0]]}]
```

[image]

This is actually the **Fig.1** from the paper.

## Calculation of `xi`

**The second integral** is simpler from the numerical point of view

```
xiN[k_?NumericQ,kc_?NumericQ,s_]:=-(1/(2π))NIntegrate[
Fs[k,q,θ,s,1]n0[1]+Fs[k,q,θ,s,-1]n0[-1],
{q,0,kc},{θ,0,2π},PrecisionGoal->4]+kc/2

xiN[k_?NumericQ,kc_?NumericQ,0]:=-(1/(2π))NIntegrate[1,
{q,0,kc},{θ,0,2π},PrecisionGoal->4]+kc   (* sum of the 1 and -1 cases*)
```

but not so simple analytically...

### Verification

```
c=30;
ival[1] =Table[{k,xiN[k,c,1]}, {k,0.1,40,2}];
ival[-1]=Table[{k,xiN[k,c,-1]},{k,0.1,40,2}];
ival[0] =Table[{k,xiN[k,c,0]}, {k,0.1,40,2}];   (*the sum of the 1 and -1 cases*)
```

against analytical solution

```
xi[k_,s_,kc_]:=kc/π (-f[k/kc]+s h2[k/kc])
Δxi[k_,s_,kc_]:=xi[k,s,kc]+kc/2
```

and plot

```
Plot[{Δxi[k,1,c],Δxi[k,-1,c],Δxi[k,1,c]+Δxi[k,-1,c]},{k,0,40},
PlotRange->{-20,20},PlotTheme->{"FrameGrid","BoldColor"},FrameStyle->14,FrameLabel->{"k","Subscript[x, i]"},Epilog->{PointSize[Medium],Blue,Point[ival[1]],Orange,Point[ival[-1]],Red,Point[ival[0]]}]
```

[image]

Thanks to the Alex Trounev answer, `h` was replaced with `h2` (**sign correction**) thereby fixing the small-$k$ behavior, however, there are still problems at high $k$ as can be seen from the plot.

Comment: Why do you have two different cases `xiN` marked the same? It is necessary to separate identifiers, for example,`xiN` and `xiN1`. Undefined `{Δxi[k,1,c,1],Δxi[k,-1,c,1],Δxi[k,1,c,1]+Δxi[k,-1,c,1]}` therefore not reproduced `Plot`

Comment: @AlexTrounev I've corrected the definitions. I was simplifying the things and forgot to remove kappa and to add the definition of  Δxi. As for the xiN, they are not the same. The 1st line defines the function for s=+1 or -1. The second line with the 3rd parameter equal to 0 defines the sum of two cases, +1 and -1. This is obtain by simplifying the sum of integrands.

Comment: Is `h2` supposed to have a big discontinuity at x=1? This must be the source of the discontinuities at k=30...

Comment: There is a problem with the analytical solution. Therefore, we need to get this solution.

Comment: @MelaGo If we assume that the sum of Δxi[k,1,c,1]+Δxi[k,-1,c,1] should be zero, which my calculations seem to show (at variance with the paper), then there should be no `f` term in the expression for `Δxi`, `h2` should be modified accordingly and it should be continuous. The reason for the separation of `xe` and `xi` into `f` and `h` is to have `s`-dependent and `s`-independent parts.

Comment: @AlexTrounev I wrote an email to the first author, but got no response. If we find a solution it might be worth to publish a comment.

Comment: @yarchik You must formulate the problem very accurately so that there is no difference between `NIntegrate[]` and `Integrate[]`, and what is formulated in the article.

Comment: @yarchik I have no idea if it makes sense physically, but it looks a lot better with `h2[x_] = Piecewise[{{x (\[Pi]/4 Log[\[Pi]/x] + \[Pi]/8) - (\[Pi]/2) x i[2], x <= 1},{ x i[1] + \[Pi]/8, x > 1}}];` and `xi[k_, s_, kc_] := (s kc/(\[Pi])) ( -f[k/kc] + h2[k/kc])` `dxi[k_, s_, kc_] := xi[k, s, kc] + s kc/2`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I managed to find an answer to my question and would like to share my experience with the community. It turns out that MA can do a lot with elliptic integrals, however, it does not know some identities, in particular Eq.8.126 from *Table Of Integrals, Series And Products*  by Gradshteyn and Ryzhik. I retype them below in original notations
$$K\!\left(\frac{2\sqrt{k}}{1+k}\right)=(1+k)K(k),$$
and
$$E\!\left(\frac{2\sqrt{k}}{1+k}\right)=\frac1{1+k}\left(2E(k)-(1-k^2)K(k)\right).$$
One should remember that they are valid for $0\le k\le 1$ and one should beware of slightly different MA conventions. We will be using the following rules

```
rules={EllipticK[(4 λ_)/(1+λ_)^2]-> (1+λ)EllipticK[λ^2],
       EllipticE[(4 λ_)/(1+λ_)^2]-> 1/(1+λ) (2EllipticE[λ^2]-(1-λ^2)EllipticK[λ^2])};
```

for simplification. Notice that for $k>1$ an imaginary part appears. Thus, we will be needing only the real part.

### Numerical verification

```
g[1]=Plot[ EllipticK[(4 k )/(k+1)^2],{k,0,3},
          PlotRange->All,PlotTheme->{"Monochrome","Frame"},
Mesh->21,MeshStyle->{Red,PointSize[Medium]},PlotStyle->None];
g[2]=Plot[Re[(1+k)EllipticK[k^2]],{k,0,3},
          PlotRange->All,PlotTheme->{"Monochrome","Frame"}];
g[5]=Show[g[2],g[1],FrameLabel->{"k","K(k^2)"},LabelStyle->14];
g[3]=Plot[ EllipticE[(4 k )/(k+1)^2],{k,0,3},
           PlotRange->All,PlotTheme->{"Monochrome","Frame"},
Mesh->21,MeshStyle->{Red,PointSize[Medium]},PlotStyle->None];
g[4]=Plot[Re[1/(1+k) (2EllipticE[k^2]-(1-k^2)EllipticK[k^2])],{k,0,3},
           PlotRange->All,PlotTheme->{"Monochrome","Frame"}];
g[6]=Show[g[4],g[3],FrameLabel->{"k","E(k^2)"},LabelStyle->14];
g[7]=GraphicsRow[{g[5],g[6]},ImageSize->800]
```

[image]

Now let us consider one particular integral that was problematic before, namely `xi`. Other integrals can be computed in a similar way.

### Computation of `xi`

Taking into account the definitions above, the integrand reads

```
ui=Simplify[Fs[k,q,θ,s,1]n0[1]+Fs[k,q,θ,s,-1]n0[-1]]
Δui=ui-1/2//Simplify
```

$$\frac12 \left[ 1-\frac{s (k-q \cos\theta)}{\sqrt{k^2+q^2-2 k q \cos\theta}}\right]$$

The constant term is trivial to integrate, we turn to the second one

$$\delta x_i=\frac1{4\pi}\int_0^{k_c}\mathrm{d}q\int_0^{2\pi}\mathrm{d}\theta\frac{s (k-q \cos\theta)}{\sqrt{k^2+q^2-2 k q \cos\theta}}$$

The angular integral reads

```
ri[1]=2 Integrate[Δui,{θ,0,π},Assumptions->k>0&&q>0&&k!=q]
(*-((s ((k+q) EllipticE[(4 k q)/(k+q)^2]+(k-q) EllipticK[(4 k q)/(k+q)^2]))/k)*)
```

now using the replacement rules

```
ri[2]=(((ri[1]/.q->x k)//Simplify)/.rules)//Simplify
(* -2 s EllipticE[x^2] *)
```

the integral takes a very simples form. We do the second integration discarding the imaginary part in accordance with the analysis above

```
ri[3]=Integrate[ri[2]/.{x-> q/k},{q,0,kc},Assumptions->kc>k>0]
(* -(1/32) k π s (-((k^2 HypergeometricPFQ[{1,1,3/2,3/2},{2,2,3},k^2/kc^2])/kc^2)+8 (1+Log[16]-2 Log[k]+2 Log[kc]-I MeijerG[{{},{1/2,1/2,1}},{{-1,0,0},{}},k^2/kc^2])) *)

ri[4]=ri[3]/.MeijerG[_,_,_]->0
(* -(1/32) k π s (-((k^2 HypergeometricPFQ[{1,1,3/2,3/2},{2,2,3},k^2/kc^2])/kc^2)+8 (1+Log[16]-2 Log[k]+2 Log[kc])) *)

ri[5]=Integrate[ri[2]/.{x-> q/k},{q,0,kc},Assumptions->k/kc>1&&kc>0]
(* -kc π s HypergeometricPFQ[{-(1/2),1/2,1/2},{1,3/2},kc^2/k^2]*)
```

### Numerical verification

```
xiN[k_?NumericQ,kc_?NumericQ,s_]:=-(1/(2π))NIntegrate[Fs[k,q,θ,s,1]n0[1]+Fs[k,q,θ,s,-1]n0[-1],{q,0,kc},{θ,0,2π},PrecisionGoal->4]+kc/2
Δxi[k_,kc_,s_]:=Piecewise[{{(k s)/4 (1/2 -(k/(4 kc))^2 HypergeometricPFQ[{1,1,3/2,3/2},{2,2,3},k^2/kc^2]+Log[(4 kc)/k]),k<=kc},{(kc s )/2 HypergeometricPFQ[{-(1/2),1/2,1/2},{1,3/2},kc^2/k^2],k>kc}}]

c=30;
ival[1]=Table[{k,xiN[k,c,1]},{k,0.1,40,2}];
ival[-1]=Table[{k,xiN[k,c,-1]},{k,0.1,40,2}];

Plot[{Δxi[k,c,1],Δxi[k,c,-1]},{k,0,40},PlotRange->{-20,20},
PlotTheme->{"FrameGrid","Monochrome","BoldColor"},
FrameStyle->14,FrameLabel->{"k","Subscript[x, i]"},Epilog->{PointSize[Medium],Blue,Point[ival[1]],Orange,Point[ival[-1]]}]
```

[image]

Thus, analytic expression for `Δxi` is the main result here.

Comment: What you've used here are basically the quadratic AGM transformations for the complete elliptic integrals.

Comment: @J.M. Do you know what AGM means? Also, people now are forgetting much about the elliptic integrals. Can you recommend some nice book on the topic?

Comment: By "AGM" I meant the classical arithmetic-geometric mean of Gauss. The most useful book that readily comes to mind was the one I linked to in my earlier answer, which is [Byrd and Friedman's](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-65138-0); if I think of others, I'll send them your way.

Comment: I also should hasten to add something about your remark, "Notice that for $k>1$ an imaginary part appears. Thus, we will be needing only the real part." You can use the formulae [here](https://dlmf.nist.gov/19.7.E3) so that you don't need to get rid of imaginary parts, which yields the replacement rule `EllipticE[(4 λ_)/(1 + λ_)^2] :> 2 λ EllipticE[1/λ^2]/(1 + λ) + (1/λ - 1) EllipticK[1/λ^2]`.

Comment: @J.M. I see, it's very useful.