# How to simplify Elliptic integrals?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, special-functions

**Context**

I would like to show that these 2 functions are identical

```
f1[a_] = (2/π) Integrate[Cos[t]/(1 -2a Cos[t] + a^2)^(3/2), {t, 0,π}, 
    Assumptions -> {0 < a < 1}] // FullSimplify
```

[image]

corresponding to this integral

$$ \frac{2}{\pi } \int_0^{\pi } \frac{\cos (\theta )}{\left(1-2 a \cos (\theta )+a^2\right)^{3/2}} \, d\theta $$

and

```
f2[a_] = (4/(π a (1 - a^2)^2))((1 + a^2) *
           EllipticE[a^2]-(1 - a^2) EllipticK[a^2])
```

[image]

This does not seem to work:

```
f2[a]/f1[a]  // FullSimplify[#, Assumptions -> {0 < a < 1}] &
```

> Any suggestions?

Comment: Some evidence, but not complete solution: `Series[f2[a] - f1[a], {a, 0, 100}, Assumptions -> {0 < a < 1}]` and `# == 0 & /@ (f2[a] - f1[a] /. a -> RandomReal[1, 100, WorkingPrecision -> 20]) // Apply[And]`

Comment: It turns out that MA can do a lot with elliptic integrals, however, it does not know some identities, in particular Eq.8.126 from *Table Of Integrals, Series And Products*  by Gradshteyn and Ryzhik. I retype them below in original notations
$K\!\left(\frac{2\sqrt{k}}{1+k}\right)=(1+k)K(k),$
and
$E\!\left(\frac{2\sqrt{k}}{1+k}\right)=\frac1{1+k}\left(2E(k)-(1-k^2)K(k)\right).$

Comment: See also comments to the answer to this post https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/204969/analytical-form-of-2d-integrals-relevant-to-graphene

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the substitution rules based on the Eq.8.126 from *Table Of Integrals, Series And Products*  by Gradshteyn and Ryzhik.  They are called quadratic arithmetic-geometric mean (AGM) transformations for the complete elliptic integrals. I retype them below in original notations
$$K\!\left(\frac{2\sqrt{k}}{1+k}\right)=(1+k)K(k),$$
and
$$E\!\left(\frac{2\sqrt{k}}{1+k}\right)=\frac1{1+k}\left(2E(k)-(1-k^2)K(k)\right).$$
One should remember that they are valid for $0\le k\le 1$ and one should beware of slightly different MA conventions.

```
rules={EllipticK[(4 λ_)/(1+λ_)^2]-> (1+λ)EllipticK[λ^2], 
EllipticE[(4 λ_)/(1+λ_)^2]-> 1/(1+λ) (2EllipticE[λ^2]-(1-λ^2)EllipticK[λ^2])};
```

Now with

```
f1[a_] = (2/π) Integrate[Cos[t]/(1 - 2 a Cos[t] + a^2)^(3/2), {t, 0, π}, 
Assumptions -> {0 < a < 1}];
f2[a_] = (4/(π a (1 - a^2)^2)) ((1 + a^2) EllipticE[a^2] -
        (1 - a^2)EllipticK[a^2]);
```

Then

```
Simplify[(f1[a] /. rules) - f2[a]]
```

returns

(* 0 *)

Comment: @chris Thank you for making my post more clear.

Comment: Thank you for your work!